# Returning 1 or 0 in column based on point location using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, attribute-table

Within QGIS - I have two layers. One is a point layer, the other is a polygon layer.

I'd like to create a column in the point's attribute table using the field calculator where 1 indicates the point is within polygon and 0 indicates the point is not within polygon.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Select by location` tool to select the points that intersect the polygon layer. The tool is located in `Vector -> Research tools -> Select by location`

[image]

When the points get selected you can update only the selected points by the value of 1 and then invert selection and update the selected (that does not intersect the polygon layer) with the value of 0. Then save edits.